How to provide different settings for debug and release version of React app in Visual Studio?
I'm writing a React app in Visual Studio as a part of React-front, Asp.Net Core-back pattern. Ultimately I will host both apps in the Azure cloud environment.
In Asp.Net Core I have a number of ways of providing different settings for debug and release environments (namely, Web.Config transforms, #if DEBUG directive or even manual msbuild commands for specific configurations). I'm quite new to React though and I'm wondering on how can I provide e.g. different endpoint URLs for local testing and for the final release version deployed on Azure?
I'm using TypeScript with Vite (defaults available in the Visual Studio template).
